# Lightweight jQuery (or non-jQuery) slider control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I need something like the slider control from jQueryUI, but I don't want to use the whole framework for only one control.

I tried searching Google but I get results for image sliders rather than the type of control I'm after. Perhaps there is another name for this kind of control?

I found only [this](http://programming.arantius.com/lightweight+javascript+slider+control)

Which is exactly what I want, but it hasn't been updated in a long time, and I don't have the facilities to make sure it works in all browsers.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about another slider control, but you only need the Core, Widget, Mouse, and Slider for jQuery UI.  Not the entire framework.

Comment: Why not just download jQuery with only the slider method. You can download a custom version with only the components you need. I've checked the download size for your components (core, mouse, widget factory, slider) and the js is 6kb gzipped, css 3kb gzipped. I wouldn't worry too much about that.

Comment: I guess that isn't too bad. It's strange though that there seem to be no other current slider controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't much to a custom jQuery UI download.

Plus, the files are available on Google's CDN.

### jQuery

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js

### jQuery UI

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js

### jQuery UI Theme

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css

Your end user may not even need to download anything new.

Comment: Why use an old theme with the newer jQuery UI version?

Comment: @Petah Good point, but it hasn't affected any of my sites yet.

Comment: It will if you use jQuery UI Buttons or Auto-Complete

Comment: Even the custom package is a little bloated considering it's just one control. I was wondering if there was any other solution (other than the one I mentioned) - if there isn't I guess I'll have to go with jQueryUI. It's not so much the bandwidth, but the page load delay.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your jQuery UI download to only include the things required for the slider

Answer (score 0):

Like Petah says in this thread, you can customize your jQuery UI download at:

http://jqueryui.com/download

Just first click all 'Deselect all' links and then start checking the components you want